# Rails Has Many Through Relationship - Difference Between New-Save and Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I checked the Rails Guides about has_many through relationship but they have a poor documentation for has_many through's effects in controllers in views.

**The models:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships
  has_many :twitter_accounts, through: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships
  has_many :projects, through: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :twitter_account
end
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :projects do
  resources :twitter_accounts
end
```

The question is, when I use the **create method**, a TwitterMembership object is being created automatically but when I use **new method** and then the **save method**, TwitterMembership is not being created. Many of the posts in Stackoverflow is saying that **create = new & save** but it seems that they are not the same.

**For example:**

```
Project.first.twitter_accounts.create(name: "bar")
```

is creating both TwitterAccount and TwitterMembership:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_accounts" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test_record"], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00]]

SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_memberships" ("created_at", "project_id", "twitter_account_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00], ["project_id", 1], ["twitter_account_id", 8], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00]]
```

But when I do the same thing in the **controllers/twitter_accounts_controller** with **new & create** - it's not creating the TwitterMembership:

```
def new
  @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new
end

def create
  @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new(twitter_account_params)
  @twitter_account.save
end
```

Can you explain me the difference between new-save and create? And is it okay if I use **create method** directly in my controller like this?

```
def create
  @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.create(twitter_account_params)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit. Here is the full controller =>**

```
class TwitterAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_twitter_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new
  end

  def create
    @twitter_account = @project.twitter_accounts.new(twitter_account_params)
    @twitter_account.save
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_twitter_account
      @twitter_account = TwitterAccount.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def twitter_account_params
      params.require(:twitter_account).permit(:name, :account_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: What does the log show for the new & then save?  They should be the same.

Comment: Nop, not the same. Just working the first SQL Query.

SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_accounts" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test_record"], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Nov 2014 22:01:06 UTC +00:00]]

Comment: I assume you're getting `@project` in a before_filter/before_action with `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])`?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the @project in before_action. I added the full controller to the question.

Comment: Quickly building an app as yours it seems it's not put in the log but the `twitter_membership` is actually created.  I have no idea why it's like that though.

Comment: Weird problem. Is it dangerous if I use "create method" directly in the controller?

Comment: I'd play around in the console. Then you can really check if the `sql` is different or the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Fix

You need to set your inverse relationships on your models to guarantee the `build` and `new` on associations will work consistently to setup the relationships, foreign keys, and intermediate associations:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships, inverse_of: :project
  
  has_many :twitter_accounts, through: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project,         inverse_of: :twitter_memberships
  belongs_to :twitter_account, inverse_of: :twitter_memberships
end

class TwitterAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :twitter_memberships, inverse_of: :twitter_account
  
  has_many :projects, through: :twitter_memberships
end
```

Which should then make this work

```
@twitter_account = Project.first.twitter_accounts.new(name: 'baz')
@twitter_account.save
```

And voila:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_accounts" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-21 19:19:06.323072"], ["name", "baz"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-21 19:19:06.323072"]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "twitter_memberships" ("created_at", "project_id", "twitter_account_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-21 19:19:06.324779"], ["project_id", 1], ["twitter_account_id", 7], ["updated_at", "2014-11-21 19:19:06.324779"]]
```

Also, using `create` is perfectly acceptable assuming you've handled all your edge cases in the event of a failure. For example: if it fails do you show an error to the end user? If it is not supposed to fail, you should raise an exception (see `create!`) to generate a notification of some sort to inform you of the failure.

### The Why

In short, without the `inverse_of` setup on `has_many`, `has_one`, and `belongs_to` Rails doesn't completely understand the chain of intermediate models that glue things together. Rails will in certain cases (like `create`) take a "best guess", and may get things right. Rails Guide doesn't make this clear, but [the documentation on inverse_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) spells this out.

It has become a Rails idiom to set `inverse_of` on all `has_many`, `has_one`, and `belongs_to` relationships, and should be done to ensure guessing by Rails is not necessary.